# What is the Poisson integral formula for?

Tags: complex-analysis

I have a homework question for complex analysis. Given a harmonic function $u(re^{i\theta})$ on the disk, show that

$$u(re^{i\theta}) = \frac 1 {2\pi} \int_0^{2\pi} P_r(\theta - \varphi)u(e^{i\varphi})d\varphi, $$

where $P_r(\gamma) = \frac {1 - r^2} {1 - 2r\cos\gamma + r^2} = \text{Re}\left(\frac{1 + re^{i\gamma}}{1-re^{i\gamma}} \right)$ is the Poisson kernel for the disk.

I have two questions

- I'm stuck trying to prove it (made an error?), halp
- What is the significance of this formula? What does it mean? How is it use?

Perhaps an answer to the second will help me figure out the first. As for the first, so far I have

Let $f = u + iv$ be holomorphic (the existence of this function was part 1 and 2 of this problem). Apply Cauchy's integral formula (as instructed by the problem):

\begin{align}
f(re^{i\theta}) &= \frac 1 {2\pi i} \int_0^{2\pi} \frac {f(e^{i\varphi})} {e^{i\varphi} - re^{i\theta}}de^{i\varphi} \\
&= \frac 1 {2\pi} \int_0^{2\pi} \frac {f(e^{i\varphi})} {1 - re^{i(\theta-\varphi)}}d\varphi ;\\
u(re^{i\theta}) &= \text{Re}\left( \frac 1 {2\pi} \int_0^{2\pi} \frac {f(e^{i\varphi})} {1 - re^{i(\theta - \varphi)}} d\varphi \right) \\
&= \frac 1 {2\pi} \int_0^{2\pi} \text{Re}\left( \frac{f(e^{i\varphi)}}{1 - re^{i(\theta - \varphi)}} \right) d\varphi \quad \text{(edit)}  \\
&= \frac 1 {2\pi} \int_0^{2\pi} \text{Re} \left( \frac{f(e^{i\varphi})(1-re^{-i(\theta - \varphi)})} 
{(1 - re^{i(\theta - \varphi)})(1 - re^{-i(\theta - \phi})} \right) d\varphi \\
&= \frac 1 {2\pi} \int_0^{2\pi} \frac{u(e^{i\varphi}) - \text{Re}\left(f(e^{i\varphi}) re^{-i(\theta - \varphi)}\right) }
{1 - 2r\cos(\theta - \varphi) + r^2} d\varphi \\
&= \frac 1 {2\pi} \int_0^{2\pi} \frac{u(e^{i\varphi}) - ru(e^{i\varphi}) \cos(\theta - \varphi) - rv(e^{u\varphi}) \sin(\theta - \varphi) }
{1 - 2r\cos(\theta - \varphi) + r^2} d\varphi 
\end{align}

So that's almost right, except now I have a v and some other junk that is supposed to be $r^2$. (Given the edit, I need to see if I'm still stuck. Answers to the first question, or hints if I'm getting off track, or corrections would still be appreciated).

Comment: Why you think that $\text{Re}\frac{A}{B}$ is the same is $\frac{\text{Re}A}{\text{Re}{B}}$? This does not hold in general. Also I do not understand how you passed the integral.

Comment: Also there are some typos in your derivation using Cauchy integral formula. You should fix it.

Comment: Ah, that's probably where it comes from. What do you mean by pass the integral? You mean put Re inside the integral? Where are the typos?

Comment: I think I found them all.

Comment: Hint: $P_{r}\rightarrow \delta\in L^{p}(\overline{D})$.

Comment: Sorry, I don't quite understand your hint. I haven't really done much analysis beyond intro courses. Does this mean as $r \to 1$, the kernel becomes a nice function on the boundary of the disk? How do I use this fact?

Comment: It means that it approximates to the Dirac delta function. You can prove in your way if you wish, but I assume it would take some effort to simplify the last expression. By the way there is a new harmless typo in the final line.

Answer (score 5):

This formula is useful because it solves the Dirichlet problem in the unit disk:
from the values of harmonic function on the boundary it finds the values inside the disk.To prove it, notice that the kernel $P_r(\theta-\phi)$ is harmonic
as a function of $z=re^{i\theta}$. This follows from the expression you give for it, as a real part of an analytic function. It remains to show that the limit
when $re^{i\theta}\to e^{i\theta_0}$ equals $u(e^{i\theta_0})$.

This is a general property which follows from the three evident properties
of the Poisson kernel: $P_r>0,$ $\int_{-\pi}^\pi P_r(t)dt=1$ and
$\lim_{r\to 1}P_r(t)=0$ for all $t\neq 0$, uniformlyon the complement of the set $|t|<\epsilon$.

It remains to notice that a harmonic function is uniquely defined by its
boundary values; this follows from the Maximum Principle.

Comment: Hi Professor Eremenko, the Poisson integral formula gives the values of a harmonic function on the interior, from knowing its values on the boundary.  Does this (known boundary values) already imply the uniqueness of the harmonic function?  Why is the Maximum Principle needed here?  Thanks @AlexandreEremenko,

Comment: @User001: you just answered your own question: what is it for. How to prove uniqueness. Suppose you have two solutions. Subtract one from another. You obtain a harmonic function, zero on the boundary. By the maximum principle is is zero everywhere. So your two solutions coincide.

Comment: Hi Professor Eremenko, hmmm...if the harmonic function is zero on the boundary, it can't be negative inside the disk? @AlexandreEremenko,

Comment: Being negative inside the disk wouldn't contradict the Maximum Principle, right?  Unless it's also something to do with the mean-value property for harmonic functions, Professor Eremenko?  Thanks, @AlexandreEremenko,

Comment: A harmonic function zero on the boundary can be neither negative nor positive inside. This is maximum principle. If $u$ is harmonic $-u$ is also harmonic.

Comment: Yes, I think I got it now, Professor Eremenko -- from applying the maximum principle to $-u$.  And also, just from thinking about the Poisson integral formula, which gives interior values from integration along the boundary, so we know the interior values would be all zero, too (perhaps the maximum principle and the Poisson integral formula might even imply one another?).  Thanks for your time, @AlexandreEremenko,